# How to use dbc.Row effectively?

Tags: python, row, plotly-dash

I'm building an app with dash-plotly but i'm confused about how to the layer correctly the items.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
from dash import dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([ #row 1
        dcc.Input(type='text'),
        html.Button('A button'),
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([ #row 2
        dcc.Dropdown(['0','1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
                 '1',
                 style={
                        'width':'10%'}),
        html.Button('A Button'),
            ])
        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The items in row #1 are inline, but the items in row #2 are stacked on each other. Both rows are composed with different elements, so how to impose the items in row #2 to be inline? What are the rules regarding dbc.Row ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here that you are using dash bootstrap components but with default stylesheet and I think you should combine `dbc.Col` with `dbc.Row` to make better layout. Here is the sample code:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
from dash import dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Input(type='text')
        ],width={'size':1,'offset':0,'order':'1'}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Button('A button'),
        ],width={'size':1,'offset':0,'order':'1'})
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(['0','1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
                         '1'),
        ],width={'size':1,'offset':0,'order':'1'}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Button('A Button'),
        ],width={'size':1,'offset':0,'order':'1'})
    ])
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

As you see, I added `external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX]` and added `dbc.Col` to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Bootstrap 5 instead using dash bootstrap components library likewise  -

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
from dash import dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = ["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"])

app.layout = html.Div([
                        html.Div([
                                  html.Div(
                                            dcc.Input(id = "input-1", type = "text", placeholder = "Enter", className = "form-control"),
                                            className = "col-lg-5"),
                                  html.Div(
                                            html.Button("Submit", id = "submit-1", className = "btn btn-dark"),
                                            className = "col-lg-3"),
                                 ], className = "row row-cols-auto mb-4"),
                        html.Div([
                                  html.Div(
                                             dcc.Dropdown(['0','1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
                                                          '1'),
                                             className = "col-lg-5"),
                                  html.Div(
                                            html.Button("Submit", id = "submit-2", className = "btn btn-dark"),
                                            className = "col-lg-3"),
                                 ], className = "row row-cols-auto")

                       ], className = "container-fluid mt-2")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)[![Sample][1]][1]
```